# How do I import multiple columns of data from an url?

Tags: java, url

I am trying to read data from a specific website. The values are tab separated values. Currently, I am trying to print the values from the last column(temperatures) but I will also be interested in reading values from the first column. I can't seem to get my code to work and actually print the values. Can someone please help? Also, any help on how to get both the first column and last at the same time would be helpful.
Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputOutput
{
   public static void readTemp()
   {

        try
        {
            URL temperature = new URL("http://academic.udayton.edu/kissock/http/Weather/gsod95-current/MNMINPLS.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new    InputStreamReader(temperature.openStream()));    //scanner to read url
            while(scan.hasNext())
            {
                String data = scan.next();                              //returns whole line
                String[] nums = data.split(",");                        //split top array
                long tempReading = Integer.parseInt(nums[5]);           //read 6th column
                System.out.println(tempReading);                        //print data in 6th column
            }//end while statement
            scan.close();
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }//end try/catch

    }//end method readTemp
}//end class InputOutput
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you told us what it was/wasn't doing.

Comment: change `Integer.parseInt(nums[5])` to `Integer.parseInt(nums[0])`?

Comment: Also, you're telling us that the data is "tab separated" but your `split` method is being passed a `,` delimiter.

Comment: I opened the url and the data actually has only 4 columns and is tab delimited

Comment: If I change my split method to ("    "); or tab separated and have Integer.parseInt(nums[0]); it only prints 1,1, 1995. These are the only values displayed whereas I want to display the entire 4th column, the temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are not reading the entire line into "data" variable. You should use scan.nextLine() method to read the entire line.

2) Use the delimiter as tab instead of a comma since its a tab separated file.

3) since the data has only 4 coloumns, accessing nums[5] would lead to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException